# Firefox equivalent on v33 to chrome's video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button selector

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, firefox

Title pretty much says it all.
I'm struggling with selecting the damn fullscreen button out of the default `<video>` skin.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on http://www.jwplayer.com/blog/using-the-browsers-new-html5-fullscreen-capabilities/:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function goFullscreen(id) {
    // Get the element that we want to take into fullscreen mode
    var element = document.getElementById(id);

    // These function will not exist in the browsers that don't support fullscreen mode yet, 
    // so we'll have to check to see if they're available before calling them.

    if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      // This is how to go into fullscren mode in Firefox
      // Note the "moz" prefix, which is short for Mozilla.
      element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
      // This is how to go into fullscreen mode in Chrome and Safari
      // Both of those browsers are based on the Webkit project, hence the same prefix.
      element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
   }
   // Hooray, now we're in fullscreen mode!
  }
</script>

<img class="video_player" src="image.jpg" id="player"></img>
<button onclick="goFullscreen('player'); return false">Click Me To Go Fullscreen! (For real)</button>
```

I see you're probably looking for the native player's selector, but this will let you create your own button.

Comment: yes i've been through these docs and what i want is the selector as i need to get it (the button) out.